# Book where ship of prisoners crashes and create a new society

Tags: story-identification, books, space

A ship of prisoners are being transported and it crashes.  Then it is about how they deal with each other and create rules.  I remember them walking. I remember a scene where a character you like didn't speak up/help someone so according to the new rules he is killed; very heartbreaking scene.  Does anyone know the title/author?

Comment: How is this related to science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: From the tagging, I'll guess this is a space ship?

Comment: Should we take it that they landed on an otherwise uninhabited planet? Or were there angry natives around whom the castaways had to learn to deal with, for instance?

Comment: This question is very terse and would be be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Do you remember the ages of the prisoners ? if they were all teenagers and you read the book relatively recently you might be looking for the book 'The 100' which was also adapted into a TV series. Either way more information is needed before we can help you

Comment: Your question lacks several details to help us find out the answer. When did you read it? When did you think it was published? What language was it written in? How many prisonners were involved in your story? From the way you wrote it, it could be within a range from just two people to a million. Also, do you remember more distinctive scenes than just "people walking"? Any name from any character, even spelled wrong, could help us at this point. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Not a perfect match, but could it possibly be Tom Godwin's *[The Survivors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Survivors_(Godwin_novel))*?

> A ship heading from Earth to Athena, a planet 500 light years away, is suddenly attacked by the Gerns, an alien empire in its expansion phase. People aboard are divided by the invaders into Acceptables and Rejects. The Acceptables would become slave labor for the Gerns on Athena, and the Rejects are forced ashore on the nearest 'Earth-like' planet, called Ragnarok. The Gerns say they will return for the Rejects, but the Rejects quickly realise that that isn't going to happen.
>
> Ragnarok has a gravity 1.5 times that of Earth, and is populated by deadly, aggressive creatures and it contains little in the way of usable metal ores. This, combined with a terrible deadly fever that kills in hours, more than decimates the population.
>
> The novels follows the stranded humans through several generations as they try to survive there, and their unswerving goal to repay the Gerns for their cruelty.

In it, a man named Bemmon is executed for hoarding food, but I don't recall him being particularly popular. It is mentioned earlier that he was ordering two teenagers around but making no effort to help them in the job they were doing.